# searching for text that contain and not contain text and symbol

Tags: regex, perl

This regex code works correctly for searching for lines that begins with an exclamation mark and does not contain colon : symbol

```
  ^!([^:\n]*)$
```

In addition to the regex code above, I need it to contain lines of text that has the word "spelling" in it, like this code below but does not work.

```
  ^!([^:\n]spelling*)$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
^![^:\n]*spelling[^:\n]*$
```

If you are looping through a file line by line, as is typical, there is no need to exclude the newlines from the match:

```
^![^:]*spelling[^:]*$
```

Another option to consider when you have complex requirements is breaking the match down into mutiple steps.  This makes for simpler, easier to understand code that is less error-prone:

```
if (/^!/ and /spelling/ and not /:/)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
spelling*
```

matches

```
spellin
spelling
spellingg
spellinggg
```

etc. You were trying for

```
^([^:\n]*spelling[^\n]*)$
```

aka

```
^([^:\n]*spelling.*)$     # Assuming /s isn't used
```

But that would allow `:` after `spelling`, so you really want

```
^([^:\n]*spelling[^:\n]*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

What about  `^([^:\n]*spelling.*)$` ?

Adding `.*` allows any character (except newline) to be present after 'spelling'

Comment: The  problem is it includes the colon : in the search when trying your solution. I need it to not include the colon : but include the word "spelling"

Comment: Removing the the ! from the regex should allow spelling to get caught then. The ^ symbol is already excluding any character you mentioned in the brackets